# How do I start my Laptop with root partition on lvm2 thin pool

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, lvm

My Laptop is configured as dual boot system with Ubuntu 14.04 (and windows 8.1). Lately I replaced the dedicated root and swap partitions with a lvm2 partition (VG (Volume Group) LinuxBereich) containing LVs (Logical Volume) LinuxSwap, LinuxRoot, and LinuxHome. There are copies of root, and home in thin pool LVs RootArea, and HomeArea named Linux_Root, and Linux_Boot.

- 3.13.0-62-generic starts or resumes correctly, from non pool LV.
- 3.13.0-63-generic doesn't find the root partition and drops to the busybox shell. After activating LVs LinuxSwap, LinuxRoot, and LinuxHome with lvm, startup proceeds without further problems.
- Neither version (62/63) starts from LV in thin pool. Attempting:
  lvm lvchange -ay LinuxBereich/Linux_Root
  (or Linux_Home, RootArea, HomeArea)
  from the busybox shell, results in:
  /sbin/modprobe failed: 1
  Cannot read thin-pool target version.
  Can't process LV Linux_Root: thin-pool target support missing from kernel ?

It would be nice if the LVs would be activated automatically in 3.13.0-63-generic.
It would be even better if the system started from thin-pool.
Any ideas are welcome. Maybe I need some more patience.
Yours
Wolfgang

Solutions:

- 3.13.0-63-generic (and 3.13.0-65-generic) starts from LV now without problem.
  Cause was a missing file in /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-63-generic that is present in /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-63-generic:
  -rw-r--r--   1 root     root          272 May  4  2012 lib/udev/rules.d/85-lvm2.rules
  Checking for such a file yielded:

> ls -l /lib/udev/rules.d/85-lvm*
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 272 May  4  2012 /lib/udev/rules.d/85-lvm2.rules.drblsave

so the file was present, but renamed.

> cp -p /lib/udev/rules.d/85-lvm2.rules.drblsave
>   /lib/udev/rules.d/85-lvm2.rules

and

> update-initramfs -u

did the trick.

For obtaining a sorted table of content of the initrd.img:

> for n in 62 63 65;do zcat /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-$n-generic|cpio
>   -itv|sort -k9>$n.lst;done

Without modification time and kernel version

> for n in 62 63 65;do sed 's/3.13.0-6./3.13.0-6?/g' $n.lst|cut -c
>   1-42,56->$n.lsu;done

- No start from thin pool LV, because of no kernel support. This is weird, because the running system is able to handle thin volumes.

  ```
  lsmod |grep -ie dm_thin_pool -e dm_persistent_data -e dm_bio_prison -e dm_bufio -e libcrc32c
  dm_thin_pool           46897  7 
  dm_persistent_data     61675  1 dm_thin_pool
  dm_bufio               27539  1 dm_persistent_data
  dm_bio_prison          15501  1 dm_thin_pool
  libcrc32c              12644  1 dm_persistent_data

  for n in  dm_thin_pool dm_persistent_data dm_bio_prison dm_bufio libcrc32c;do modinfo $n;done|grep filename:|sort -u
  filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-65-generic/kernel/drivers/md/dm-bio-prison.ko
  filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-65-generic/kernel/drivers/md/dm-bufio.ko
  filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-65-generic/kernel/drivers/md/dm-thin-pool.ko
  filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-65-generic/kernel/drivers/md/persistent-data/dm-persistent-data.ko
  filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-65-generic/kernel/lib/libcrc32c.ko
  ```

So a file /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/lvm2thin was created:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    PREREQ=""
    prereqs()
    {
         echo "$PREREQ"
    }

    case $1 in
    prereqs)
         prereqs
         exit 0
         ;;
    esac

    . /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions
    # Begin real processing below this line
    copy_exec /lib/modules/${version}/kernel/drivers/md/dm-thin-pool.ko
    copy_exec /lib/modules/${version}/kernel/drivers/md/dm-bio-prison.ko
    copy_exec /lib/modules/${version}/kernel/drivers/md/dm-bufio.ko
    copy_exec /lib/modules/${version}/kernel/drivers/md/persistent-data/dm-persistent-data.ko
```

Set proper permissions.

```
    chmod 755 /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/lvm2thin 
    ls -l /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/lvm2thin 
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 583 Okt  8 18:16 /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/lvm2thin
```

and again

> update-initramfs -u

done.